# Inserting custom String between number and decimal - Java DecimalFormat

Tags: java, html, number-formatting, decimalformat

Hello and thank you in advance for the help.

I am having some trouble formatting using a Java function to mark up a price in HTML.

It seems that, no matter what I do, I cannot insert custom content between the numbers and the decimal (throws Illegal Argument Exception). Is there any known way to achieve the following:

```
NumberFormat nf = getNumberFormat("'<span class=\"dollars\">'##'</span></span class=\"decimal\">'.'</span></span class=\"cents\">'00'</span>'", locale);
nf.format(number);
```

Assume locale and number are correctly initialized.

Comment: What is `getNumberFormat`? Does it just call the DecimalFormat constructor?

Comment: Factory method for getting a NumberFormat object, it's not the problem here.

Comment: It may not be the problem, but it's *code we can't see*. How are we meant to diagnose what's wrong with code we can't see? I've written my answer *assuming* it just calls the `DecimalFormat` constructor, but it would have been nice if you'd given us a complete code sample instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet I mentioned the problem was the illegal argument exception

Comment: Yes, but how is that meant to help? You've basically said: "I've called a method which I'm not going to show you, and it's thrown an IllegalArgumentException." The code in `getNumberFormat` could be completely ignoring the parameters for all we know. It's in *your* interest to present the code - you're the one who will gain from an answer. Don't make potential answerers guess. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs for `DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) you'll see that they talk about the prefix and the suffix text - but not putting arbitrary text *within* a number.

It sounds like you should basically write this bit of formatting yourself - possibly using `DecimalFormat` for each *section* of the number.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using String.format(String pattern, Object... arguments).  You can pass your simply formatted numbers as arguments.